# 'gmail' versus 'google-mail'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

I just found a question tagged bot, [google-mail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-mail) (x2) *and* [gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (x198). Does that really make sense? One could argue the former is for the service, while the latter is for the app. Wrong: Both questions tagged 'google-mail' are about the app (GMail app setup, install google apps).

Thinking about it: All our google apps tags tart with `google-*` (e.g. `google-play-[store|music|books|movies]`, or `google-[maps|talk|voice|calendar|plus|...]`. So a tag like `google-mail` makes absolutely sense to me, and would count as "consolidation". Hence my suggestion:

Merge the two making `google-mail` the master and `gmail` a synonym to it. There's not a lot of tag wiki for either of them (just an excerpt on `gmail` which could easily be cut'n'paste (for Germans: Guttenberg-Schavant ;)).

Comment: TBH, I would have thought the other way would make more sense. Do people actually refer to it as "Google Mail" anymore? The official branding is simply "Gmail", whereas the other ones are all officially "Google [whatever]" (Maps, Play, etc) so their tags follow the actual names. /cc @Flow

Comment: People can still use the gmail tag. It will just be rewritten to google-mail. Most people I know refer to it as 'Google Mail'. But that may depends on where you live. gmail was a trademark in germany, so google couldn't use it for years.

Comment: @Flow: They can still "use" it, sure, but the tag will not display as "gmail". I guess that simply seems counterintuitive to me since the name of the app (and web service) is "Gmail".

Comment: If you want to match the format of the existing tags, `google-maps`, `google-calendar`, etc. then shouldn't be `google-gmail`?! (Although I wouldn't recommend that.) We had the same issue in the UK... it was officially known as Googlemail for a long time, and I still encounter these email addresses. However, we still used the term gmail in common usage. I'm torn, but I think gmail is a special case.

Comment: The name of the product is Gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. By popular demand [google-mail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-mail) now points to [gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail).

Comment: The official name for the app is "[Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm)".